# In Jolt, can we loop through nested array and still use the index of outer array to form a single array output? Please refer to example:

Tags: json, jolt

I would need to loop through users and create a new array that follows the existing sequence but the result array should not have a nested array as shown in expected output.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "firstName": "Abc",
      "lastName": "Def"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "subUsers": [
        {
          "subUserFirstName": "Mno",
          "subUserLastName": "Pqr"
        },
        {
          "subUserFirstName": "Stu",
          "subUserLastName": "Vwi"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "A",
      "firstName": "Ghi",
      "lastName": "Jkl"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output** :

```json
{
  "staffs": [
    {
      "staffFirstName": "Abc",
      "staffLastName": "Def"
    },
     {
      "staffFirstName": "Mno",
      "staffLastName": "Pqr"
    },
     {
      "staffFirstName": "Stu",
      "staffLastName": "Vwi"
    },
     {
      "staffFirstName": "Ghi",
      "staffLastName": "Jkl"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accumulate them at the common level at the first **shift** transformation spec, and then rename the attributes within the second one such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*Name": "x&1.&",
          "subUsers": {
            "*": {
              "*": "y&1.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*irst*": "staffs[#2].staffFirst&(0,2)", // &(0,2) is a replacement of "Name" as it's from the current(0) level with the place of 2nd asterisk 
        "*ast*": "staffs[#2].staffLast&(0,2)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Note that the value expressions within the first spec are qualified with two distinct arbitrary letters `x` and `y` rather than using the `&2` which is replacement of the array names( `users`,`subUsers` ), since those names would be identical and that would yield wrong result then.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros! It works as expected. However I have a more complicated json structure where I need to implement this transformation keeping other parts as it is.
I will try to incorporate this in my actual spec file.